# uvm_reg_predictor predict not working

Tags: verification, uvm

In my environment, I have connected predictor bus_in port to output analysis port of monitor. I have also implement reg_adapter bus2reg function and connect adapter to predictor.

I'm using passive prediction (https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/registers/integrating). The mirror value of uvm_reg should be updated automaticly as long as there's transaction sent from monitor. However I did not see that happen. When I check the source code for uvm_reg_predictor, it seems like it failed in get_reg_by_offset() function so that it did not get uvm_reg object. Did anyone has similar issue? If so, what's your solution? Thanks.

Comment: add some code! If you are able to create a small example, all the better

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by configuring the offset in the REG map.

Make sure that the transactions (address) received by adapter and the address in the REG map are same. Add `set_auto_predict(0)` for turning off implicit prediction. The `reg_offset` failed since there was an address mismatch and Mapping was not happening henceforth the predict method for that register was not getting called implicitly.